# CSS nested class selector

Tags: css

I am using this code to select a nested class:

```
.carousel-item > .item-box > .details > .name {
  color: black;
}
```

Is there a simple way to select the `.name` class but only when it's inside `.carousel-item` ?

Comment: `.carousel-item .name `will work but it could also target other elements. It depends on your markup

Comment: My comment (and the current answer) is stil valid: if you have other `.name` elements in-between or as not direct children as in your selector, the shorter version will work but it's not equivalent because potentially it could match a larger set of elements. So you should check your markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.carousel-item .name`

It will do the job. In case it doesn't matter if the `.name` is nested under `.item-box` and `.details`

Answer (score 1):

As fcalderan answered, this works:

```css
 
.a .c {color:red}
```

```html
<div class="c">Black</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">Red</div>
  </div>
</div>
```